# Java confuses variables of a class with another instance of a class

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that has creatures battle each other. I have a class called Creature, which takes integer inputs for attack, speed, and health, respectively.
Whenever I try to make a new instance of the Creature class, and try to reference it using methods, it thinks I'm talking about the newest instance of the class.

```
Creature c = new Creature(1,2,3);
c.getStats();
```

This prints out Attack: 1 Speed: 2 Health: 3

However, if I create a new Creature...

```
Creature c = new Creature(1,2,3);
c.getStats();
Creature b = new Creature(9,9,9);
c.getStats();
```

As you can see, I'm referencing the same creature twice. But, I get different results. Even if I specifically state the creature I'm talking about is c, it'll go for the newest instance of the Creature class instead. I believe what's happening is that Java is replacing c's variables with. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you assigning the parameter values to static fields inside `Creature`? just guessing...

Comment: You need to show the code for `getStats()`. @morgano's theory is most likely correct.

Comment: Post your Creature.java here. If you have your fields static, it wont work. Post the contents?

Comment: You example is using `c.getStats()`, but never uses `b`

Comment: Also, when you are learning a new technology, your gut reaction to things not working the way you wanted them to should be "I must be misunderstanding how the technology works" rather than "the technology must be doing things wrong". (This is not meant as an insult to you; it applies equally well to me and other professional programmers whenever we are learning new languages.)

Comment: Post the code for your Creature class, it's likely that it has static fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is clearly on the line of code that you instantiate (create) the second `Creature` object called `b`. Since you didn't post your constructor for `Creature`, I guess in the constructor you assigned the values passed in to a *static* variable. Every class has *one* static variable per application domain.

So that's why you get different results. Static variables change no matter which object you call on. Thus, calling the constructor the second time will overwrite the value that you just assigned to the static variable.

Now you can try creating another `Creature` and call

```
c.getStats()
```

again and you will see different results.

To solve this, you need to go into your `Creature` class and look for the variables that stores the stats of the creatures. There should be a word "`static`". And you should delete that.